# gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml - 404 error?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-appengine-node

I have a dispatch.yaml that has been working forever.  I just tried to update it and redeploy with

```
gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml
```

The response I get is

```
Configurations to update:

descriptor:      [/home/xxxxxxx/dispatch.yaml]
type:            [routing rules]
target project:  [xxxxxxxxxx]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

Updating config [dispatch]...failed.                                                                                           
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Server responded with code [404]:
  Not Found Unexpected HTTP status 404.
  b'\n<html><head>\n<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">\n<title>404 Page not found</title>\n</head>\n<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>\n<h1>Error: Page not found</h1>\n<h2>The requested URL was not found on this server.</h2>\n<h2></h2>\n</body></html>\n'
```

The yaml is valid. In any case this doesn't look like an issue with my files, it looks more like an app engine problem? What is going on here?  How can I fix this?

Suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

....aaand as if my magic it's working again.  I guess Google was having a bad day ¯\*(ツ)*/¯